# Almacenar horas grande en python

Tags: python, django

Tengo una variable en una tabla de mi modelo que se llama `duracion` que es de tipo `TimeField`, ahí voy almacenar la duración total de las llamadas, tanto en horas, minutos como en segundos, que realiza una persona en un periodo de tiempo determinado. El problema es que cuando ya esa cantidad pasa de las 24 horas me pone cualquier valor menor de 24. ¿Hay alguna forma de especificar que las horas van a ser mayor que 24?

Answer (score 1):

Desde la versión 1.8 de Django se puede utilizar el tipo [`DurationField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DurationField).

Es lo más recomendable para almacenar periodos de tiempo mediante `timedelta`.